# How to make `goBack()` method of history to ignore hash (#)?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have some routes that are using `/routename#somefilter`. This is not a completely different route, it's just a filter flag we use.

However, whenever I access `/routename#somefilter` and click on the back button in our app, it goes back to `/routename` instead of an actual previous route (e.g. I came from `/anotherroutename` before going to `/routename`).

How do I make `history` from react-router ignore the hash routes? I am using `useHistory()` hook by the way.

Comment: Are you using history.push to add it in url?

Comment: @AmitChauhan Yes using push to add # to the path..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of doing `history.push` use `history.replace` to update url. 
`history.push` add new entry to router history, so if you use `history.replace`, current entry in history.